# Upload a Pandas DataFrame as Excel file directly to Google Drive using PyDrive

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, pydrive

I'm trying to write a `pandas.DataFrame` directly to Google Drive, without first writing the file out locally. I can't find a solution and not sure if it is even possible. I've tried the code below, but I get an `AttributeError`.

```
import pandas as pd
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LoadCredentialsFile(mycreds)
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2],'b':[2,3]})

f = drive.CreateFile({'id': '0B_6_uVX9biFuX0FJWFkt'}) #test.xlsx file
f.SetContentString(df) 
f.Upload()
```

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: Consider creating a temp file, uploading it, and then deleting it?

Comment: A dataframe does not have a native storage format.  What format do you want it to be stored as?

Comment: @StephenRauch I'd like to save it as an Excel file. And specifically overwrite an existing file daily using the file id from Google Drive.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get `pandas` to write an Excel file directly to a string like:

#### Code:

```
wb = Workbook()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('', engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = wb
df.to_excel(writer)
file_as_string = save_virtual_workbook(wb)
```

#### Full Code:

Here is the above code combined with your example.  Please note that this part is untested.

```
import pandas as pd
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LoadCredentialsFile(mycreds)
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [2, 3]})

from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl.writer.excel import save_virtual_workbook

wb = Workbook()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('', engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = wb
df.to_excel(writer)

f = drive.CreateFile({'id': '0B_6_uVX9biFuX0FJWFkt'}) #test.xlsx file
f.SetContentString(save_virtual_workbook(wb))
f.Upload()
```

Comment: I suggest avoiding `ExcelWriter` altogether as openpyxl has pretty good support for Dataframes http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pandas.html

Comment: I get an error message: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)` when I run this.

Comment: Python 2 or 3?  Which line is complaining? Is that with the sample dataframe?

Comment: Python 2. `UnicodeDecodeError ...
---> 12 f.SetContentString(save_virtual_workbook(wb))`

Comment: Is that the sample dataframe?, Also seperate the `SetContentString` from the `save_virtual_workbook` to see which is having the problem

Comment: Okay, did this: `vw = save_virtual_workbook(wb)`
`f.SetContentString(vw)` SetContentString is giving me the error. The dataframe is the same the example.

Comment: I do not have access to the `SetContentString` stuff, So I won't be much help there.

Comment: I cannot pass an empty string as path to the ExcelWriter. In order to make this work regardless, I introduced a temp file.